# Python 3.3: Functions calling other functions

Tags: python, function

Greetings Pythonic world. Day 5 of learning Python and I am grappling with functions that call other functions. This will be simple to some people...

In this code:

```
def powers_of_x(x):
    print ('Powers Function with ', x, ' entered:')
    for n in range (-3,  4,  1):
        print ('power of ', n,  "= ",  x**n)
    return 'First one ended (using variables with defined range)'

def powers_of_9():
    print ("Powers function for 9 is:")
    powers_of_x(9)
    return 'Second one ended (no passed variable here)'

def combined():
    x = int(input('Enter value to start:'))
    print ('First, run powers_of_x function for entered value of: ',  x)
    powers_of_x(x)
    print ('Second, run powers_of_9 function for powers of 9:')
    powers_of_9()
    return 'All now finished.'
```

The first function `powers_of_x(x)` works fine on its own. So does the second, `powers_of_9()`. In both cases, the printed `return` message appears.

But when they are called by the third function `combined()`, the final `return` message from each ('First one ended...' and 'Second one ended...') is not printed. Why not? "All now finished" appears, as it should. Thank you for any corrections.

[Edited] Sorry, I might not be stating this well. My question was why the text "First one ended..." and "Second one ended..." appear when the first two functions are run separately, but not when the function `combined()` runs. Is this a feature of `return`? If so, I will stick to using `print`.

Comment: FYI, return values are typically not parenthesized in Python code. It's more common to write `return 'some string'` than `return ('some string')`.

Comment: @senshin Thank you for this - parentheses now removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question was why the text "First one ended..." and "Second one ended..." appear when the first two functions are run separately, but not when the function combined() runs.

It looks like you're running your code at the interactive prompt (either in IDLE or on the command line). At the interactive prompt, when you run a function and *don't* assign its return value to anything, the return value is printed to the screen. If you do assign its return value to a variable, or if the function isn't top-level, the return value is not printed to the screen. For example:

```python
>>> def foo():
    return 3

>>> def bar():
    foo()

>>> foo()     # not assigned to anything -> prints return value to output
3
>>> bar()     # not top-level -> doesn't print return value to output
>>> x = foo() # assigned to x -> doesn't print return value to output
```

This is a quirk of the interactive prompt. You will not get the same results if e.g. you add the line `powers_of_9()` to the end of the file and then run it. When you do that, your results look like this:

```
Powers function for 9 is:
Powers Function with  9  entered:
power of  -3 =  0.0013717421124828533
power of  -2 =  0.012345679012345678
power of  -1 =  0.1111111111111111
power of  0 =  1
power of  1 =  9
power of  2 =  81
power of  3 =  729
```

As you can see, the return value of `powers_of_9` is not printed.

In any case, the way you are using the `return` statement is not correct. You should use `return` only when you want to extract some information from a function for use elsewhere. For example, like this silly example:

```python
def add(x, y):
    return x+y

def print_two_plus_three():
    result = add(2, 3)
    print(result)
```

When you just want to display some information, `print` is what you should use.

---

Also, I would like to offer some commentary on your code. To achieve the results you want, your code should probably look something like this:

```python
def powers_of_x(x):
    print('Powers function with', x, 'entered:')
    for n in range(-3, 4, 1):
        print('power of', n, '=', x**n)
    print('First one ended (using variables with defined range)')

def powers_of_9():
    print('Powers function for 9 is:')
    powers_of_x(9)
    print('Second one ended (no passed variable here)')

def combined():
    x = int(input('Enter value to start: '))
    print('First, run powers_of_x function for entered value of:', x)
    powers_of_x(x)
    print('Second, run powers_of_9 function for powers of 9:')
    powers_of_9()
    print('All now finished')
```

- When you write `print('abc', 'def', 'ghi')`, the printed string is `abc def ghi`. That is, each argument to print is separated by a space. You can alter this behavior by writing e.g. `print('abc', 'def', 'ghi', sep='X')`, where the `sep` keyword argument specifies what string should be used to separate arguments. As you might guess, this prints `abcXdefXghi`.
- As I commented, it is considered bad style to parenthesize `return` values (unless you're returning a tuple, of course).
- It is also considered bad style to put a space between the function name and the list of arguments. i.e. use `print('foo')`, not `print ('foo')`.
- It is nice to put a space at the end of the argument to `input()`, so that the inputted values are separated from the input prompt.

Comment: Thank you for the constructive criticism. Much appreciated. Just one query: when running your code above, the last three lines output are:

`First one ended (using variables with defined range)
Second one ended (no passed variable here)
All now finished`

In other words, `First one ended` is printed twice (once after the first function has run, then again before the second function finishes. Why is that?

Comment: @ShaneMHewitt Let's look at the sequence of function calls that happens. First, we start by calling `combined` to get the whole thing going. On line 3 of `combined`, we call `powers_of_x`, and so that function runs, and finishes by printing "First one ended..." once. Once that's done, we come back to `combined`. On line 5 of `combined`, we call `powers_of_9`, so we step into that. `powers_of_9` calls `powers_of_x`, so we run that function _again_, which means that we print "First one ended..." _again_. (cont...)

Comment: @ShaneMHewitt (cont...) Only once `powers_of_x` is done do we step back into `powers_of_9` and print "Second one ended...". And of course, once `powers_of_9` is done, we step back into `combined` and finish up by printing "All now finished". If you're confused about how this works, try following your code line by line and writing out what each line does by hand (i.e. pretend to be the Python interpreter).

Comment: That all makes sense now. I appreciate your explanation and your time. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You are ignoring the return values of your functions. If you want to print them, add `print()`:

```
print(powers_of_x(x))
```

etc.

That said, it would seem more logical to simply change the `return` statements to `print()`.

Comment: The output of the first two functions prints fine. It is the text following the 'return' commands that isn't printing, when called from the third function. I just changed the three return statements to print, and I'm getting "unhandled syntax errors".

Answer (score 1):

Because they are being returned, not printed. They are returning a string, but in combined() those strings are not being assigned to anything.

You could say:

```
my_string = powers_of_x(9)
print(my_string)
```

Or simply:

```
print(powers_of_x(9))
```